# Relationship data inside getAttribute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a one-to-many relationship defined in Laravel:

`TheModules` has many `TheModulesActions` and `TheModulesActions` has one `TheModules`.

It works well, however I would like to set a custom attribute inside `TheModulesActions` called `url`.

To achieve that I need the following code:

```
  protected $appends = array('url');

  public function getUrlAttribute() {
      $nameURL = SharedMethods::slugify($this->title);
      $url = "#/control/{$module}/{$nameURL}/{$this->id}";
      return $url;
  }
```

Till now everything works, however `$module` variable is empty, all I have is `$this->moduleID` which is linked to `TheModules`.

I need `$this->TheModules()->title` but it doesn't work inside my `getUrlAttribute` method.

Is there any way to access relationship data inside `getAttribute`?

## EDIT

The Relationships in `TheModulesActions` class are:

```
  public function TheModule() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TheModules');
  }
```

The Relationships in `TheModules` class are:

```
  public function TheActions() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\TheModulesActions', 'moduleID');
  }
```

Tried `$this->TheModules->title`:

Gives me this error:

ErrorException in TheModulesActions.php line 15:
Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can it by dropping the parenthesis `()` on the relation name as:

```
$this->TheModules->title
```

When you use parenthesis with relation name then Laravel returns an instance of query builder.

Comment: ErrorException in TheModulesActions.php line 15:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Can you show the relationships in `TheModulesActions` class? I am hoping your relation name in `TheModulesActions` class is `TheModules()`.

Comment: Make sure you have the relation in your DB for the current `TheModulesActions`. You can test using `dd($this->TheModules)`. If it returns `null` then there is some mistake in defining your relation or there is no relation in your DB.

Comment: just fixed the issue, the issue was a wrong relationship. This was the solution: `return $this->hasOne('App\TheModules', 'id', 'moduleID');`